# Designing a unit-test framework for writing custom tests in CLIPS for CLIPS rules, using a multi-file setup

Tags: testing, clips

I'd like to make a unit-test like framework that allows me to write custom tests for individual rules. I'd like each test to be in it's own file, i.e. `test_R1.clp` would be the test file for rule **R1**. Each test should be able to load it's own facts file. I've tried many variations of the following, including using a different *defmodule* for each file. Is what I'm trying to do even possible in CLIPS? If so, what else is needed to make this work?

I'd like to run my tests via:

> `$CLIPSDOS64.exe -f2 .\test_all.clp`

With the current example, the error I get is 
`[EXPRNPSR3] Missing function declaration for setup-tests.`

I've gotten a single test to work correctly using a unique *defmodule* for each file (i.e. UNITTEST for the testing framework and R1 for the test_R1 file). However, I would still get errors because of the automatic switching between focus statements when files are loaded, or when functions are defined in other files. I've looked at the basic and advanced CLIPS programming guides, but if I've missed something there, please let me know.

Other specific questions:

1. Since some tests may load facts that overwrite existing facts, how do I prevent getting errors from redefining existing facts? Do I need to do a `(clear)` in between running each test?

**TestingFramework.clp:**

```
;;; File: TestingFramework.clp

(defglobal ?*tests-counter* = 0)
(defglobal ?*all-tests-passed* = TRUE)
(defglobal ?*failed-tests-counter* = 0)

(deftemplate test_to_run
   (slot testid)
   (slot testname)
   (slot testsetupfunc)
   (slot testcheckfunc))

(deffunction test-check (?test-name ?test-condition)
   (if (eval ?test-condition)
       then (printout t "SUCCESS: Test " ?test-name crlf)
            (printout test_results_file "SUCCESS: Test " ?test-name crlf)
            (return TRUE)
       else (printout t "FAILURE: Test " ?test-name crlf)
            (printout test_results_file "FAILURE: Test " ?test-name crlf)
            (return FALSE)))

(deffunction setup_tests ()
    (open "test_summary_results.txt" test_results_file "w"))

(deffunction finish_tests ()
    (close test_results_file))

(deffunction add_test (?test-name ?test-setup-func ?test-check-func)
    (bind ?*tests-counter* (+ 1 ?*tests-counter*))
    (assert (test_to_run (testid ?*tests-counter*)
                         (testname ?test-name)
                         (testsetupfunc ?test-setup-func)
                         (testcheckfunc ?test-check-func))))

(deffunction run_all_tests ()
    (printout t "About to run " ?*tests-counter* " test(s):" crlf)
    (do-for-all-facts ((?ttr_fact test_to_run)) TRUE
        (funcall (fact-slot-value ?ttr_fact testsetupfunc))
        (if (funcall (fact-slot-value ?ttr_fact testcheckfunc))
            then (printout t "    SUCCESS" crlf)
            else (printout t "    FAILURE" crlf)
                 (bind ?*failed-tests-counter* (+ 1 ?*failed-tests-counter*))
                 (bind ?*all-tests-passed* FALSE)))
    (if ?*all-tests-passed*
        then (printout t "All " ?*tests-counter* " tests passed successfully." crlf)
        else (printout t ?*failed-tests-counter* "/" ?*tests-counter* " tests failed." crlf)))
```

**tests\test_R1.clp:**

```
;;; File: test_R1.clp
;;; Tests for Rule 1

(deffunction R1_TEST_1_SETUP ()
    (load* "FluidSystem_facts_demo.clp")
    (load* "FluidSystem_rules_demo.clp")
    (reset))

(deffunction R1_TEST_1 ()
    (send [JacketWaterInletTempReading] put-hasValue 35.0)
    (send [JacketWaterInletTempReading] put-hasValueDefined DEFINED)
    (send [JacketWaterOutletTempReading] put-hasValue 37.0)
    (send [JacketWaterOutletTempReading] put-hasValueDefined DEFINED)
    (run)
    (return (member$ [DissimilarHighTempFlowRate] (send [CounterFlowHeatExchanger] get-hasIssue))))
```

**test_all.clp:**

```
;;; File: test_all.clp
;;; Run tests via:
;;; CLIPSDOS64.exe -f2 .\test_all.clp

(load* "TestingFramework.clp")
(setup-tests)

;;; Test R1
(load* "tests\\test_R1.clp")
(add_test (test_to_run "R1_TEST_1" R1_TEST_1_SETUP R1_TEST_1))
(clear)  ;; unsure if this is needed

;;; ... more tests to follow

(run_all_tests)

(finish_tests)
```

Answer (score 0):

The CLIPS regression tests use a framework that might serve your needs. You can download it (clips_feature_tests_640.zip) from one of the 6.4 download directories (sourceforge.net/projects/clipsrules/files/CLIPS/6.40_Beta_3/ for the current beta release). To run the tests, launch CLIPS in the same directory and execute a (batch "testall.tst") command. Using the CLIPS terminal application, you can also run them from the shell with "clips -f testall.tst". When execution completes you can look at the *.rsl files in the Results directory for the results. If difference occurs you can use a diff program to compare the contents of the .out file in the Actual directory with the contents of the Expected directory.

The framework uses the batch command to automatically load and run the test cases. The dribble-on command is used to capture the output of each test case and place it in its own file in the Actual directory. The framework allows you to run all of the test cases (using the testall.tst batch file) or you can run any of the individual test cases by running the .tst batch file associated with the test.

Comment: Thank you Gary! I'll give this a try

Comment: If I wanted to make my own tests, do I need to create my own .bat file and .tst file, run them, save the output into a .out file that I than store in the Expected folder, and then later when I run the test again, I check to see that the Actual output matches the Expected?